# Unix Shell script to monitor a folder for files with user details

Tags: shell, unix

I have below requirement where I want to monitor a folder for file activity and user who is doing that.

I know something call inotify tools but will that work on all unix versions like HP, Solaris etc?

And how to track name of user/id who doing that file add/delete/modify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know something call inotify tools but will that work on all unix
>   versions like HP, Solaris etc?

`inotify` is a Linux-only solution.  There are approximately similar solutions available for other operating systems (e.g., Solaris has [file event notifications](https://solarisrants.wordpress.com/2013/07/24/solaris-file-event-notification/), but I don't know that there is anything available that wraps them up in a single API.

> And how to track name of user/id who doing that file add/delete/modify?

You can't, at least not in a cross-platform manner.  Under Linux you can probably accomplish a task like this using the `audit` subsystem, but that is again a Linux-only solution.

Comment: I need only for Unix machine, do you have more details around audit?

Comment: That was "Linux"-only, not "Unix"-only.  A brief search for "linux audit" will probably yield a trove of useful documentation, including a [quick overview](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/01/a-brief-introduction-to-auditd/) from our friends at StackExchange.